# Version control of add-ons

Tags: geometry-nodes, add-on

I have a couple questions in regards to add-ons, version controls, and how changes to add-on features get handled when loading .blend files that used previous add-on versions.

I am using an add-on that encodes a whole bunch of geometry nodes. That add-on gets updated fairly regularly where I want to quickly implement the updates to nodes used in previous projects' blend files. So my questions are:

1. How does Blender natively handle add-on versions? Can I have two different versions of the add-on installed but only import one or the other for a specific blender instance? I've gone into the add-ons **init**.py script changed the bl_info['name'] dictionary value to a versioned name of the add-on so that I don't get a redundancy error/warning when looking to import add-ons in the GUI. So, I don't have a surface-level naming convention issue. But this setup does seem to result in ModuleNotFoundError messages so there may be some internal name spaces that aren't behaving as I expected.
2. Situation: I have a blender project using an outdated version of an add-on saved in a blend file. I update the add-on. I load up the project's blend file. Why aren't the geometry nodes used in the project's node tree not getting updated? Even when I pull out fresh nodes, they are the outdated version. I think this has something to do with the blend file explicitly storing parameters and configurations of nodes used in the graph. Then when I load the blend file, it overwrites the updated add-on's versions of the nodes? What's best practices way of avoiding/fixing this?

Thanks for you time!